# Directive invoked before module configuration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have defined angular module:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     angular.module('pcc', [...
     ])
     .config(configuration)
     .run(runner);

     function configuration(..., $compileProvider) {
         angular.module('pcc').compileProvider = $compileProvider;
     }

     function runner(...) {

     }
})();
```

And directive in seperate file:

```
angular.module('pcc').compileProvider
    .directive('report', function (...) {
        return {
            ...
        }
    });
```

I would like to implement lazy loading of the directive, and that requires compileProvider which is available when module configuration is invoked.

The problem is the directive is invoked before configuration is finished, thus compileProvider is undefined.

Any way to solve that?